# How to send a http response with "Transfer-Encoding: trunked" in GO

Tags: http, go

I want to send my response data to to client with "Transfer-Encoding:trunked".
But I do not find the way to do it with Golang.
Is there any example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The net/http server does not allow the application to control the transfer encoding.

The net/http server automatically uses chunked encoding when the application does not set the Content-Length response header and the connection can be reused (http/1 client requested keep-alive or http/1.1 client did not request connection close).

Comment: when server automatically uses chunked encoding, what

Comment: thanks, and one more question. What is the default content-length when server uses chunked encoding automatically.

Comment: The content length is not specified when chunked encoding is used.